# Как сделать закладки в описании товара opencart

Tags: opencart

Здравствуйте! Допустим есть "отзывы" и "описание".Как добавить еще вкладку "  характеристика"? Весь инет просмотрела...Может не там ищу?... Подскажите пожалуйста:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> site/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl

В этом файле расположены все табы, выводимые на странице товара. Если стоит что-то вроде vqmod, то там вроде как-то модулем можно.

Но вкладка "характеристики" подразумевает собой какие-то параметры, принадлежащее товару. Тут уже нужно создавать таблицу под эти характеристики и добавлять в админку управления товаром вкладку для изменения этих характеристик. А создание характеристики обычно присваивают настройкам категории. Короче мороки по самые не хочу.

Скачайте лучше какой-нибудь готовый плагин.

Comment: спасибо за ответ:) Я уже разобралась:)Нашла бесплатный плагин, правда пришлось немного поковыряться..Но ничего все работает:)

Answer (score 0):

**Админка - каталог - Атрибуты**:
1.**Группы Атрибутов** - создаёте группу, например "размер"
2.**Атрибуты** - создаёте набор атрибутов для группы.
В итоге подтянется таблица "характеристики" в новый таб.
Это стандартный функционал opencart. Редактировать файл .tpl рекомендую только в случае, когда вам необходимо кардинально изменить html-шаблон вывода табов. До того всё решается css-ами.